# CSS/JS: Triggering remote text glowing effect with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to combine these two examples that I have.
At the moment I have this:

```
Nouns - Verbs

I like to ride my bicycle every day.
```

When you hover over "Nouns" all the nouns in the sentence glow and the same kind of thing for "Verbs". That is achieved by this example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/r4hqxvbs/3/)):

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span id ="noun">Nouns</span> - <span id="verb">Verbs</span>
</p>

I 
<span class="verb">like</span> 
to 
<span class="verb">ride</span> 
my 
<span class="noun">bicycle</span> 
every 
<span class="noun">day</span>.
```

CSS

```
#verb {

}

.verb {
text-shadow: none;
display: inline;
}
#noun {

}

.noun {
text-shadow: none;
display: inline;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#verb").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".verb").css("text-shadow", "0 0 3px blue");
    });
    $("#verb").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".verb").css("text-shadow", "");
    });

    $("#noun").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".noun").css("text-shadow", "0 0 3px red");
    });
    $("#noun").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".noun").css("text-shadow", "");
    });
});
```

But the glowing effect I have is too instant on and off, I want to have a nice transition, like this other example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/z3Lxmtue/1/)):

HTML

```
<div class="confirm_selection">[ Confirm Selection ]</div>
```

CSS

```
.confirm_selection {
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;

    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    opacity: 1;

}
.confirm_selection:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

Can someone show me how to combine these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also toggle classes so that on hover of #noun, it adds .noun-hovered to .noun and put the transition on .noun. That way your javascript could be only removing/adding classes. seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/okhceoLk/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#verb").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".verb").addClass("verb-hovered");
  });
 $("#verb").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".verb").removeClass("verb-hovered");
  });

  $("#noun").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".noun").addClass("noun-hovered");
  });
  $("#noun").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".noun").removeClass("noun-hovered");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
 .verb,.noun {
   text-shadow: none;
   display: inline;
   transition: text-shadow 1s;
 }

 .verb-hovered {
   text-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
 }

 .noun-hovered {
   text-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add transition css in javascript.Might be this can help you.

```
  $("#verb").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".verb").css({"transition": "text-shadow 0.2s linear","text-shadow":"0 0 3px blue"});
    });
```